# Objective c: Change languages via NSLocalizedString for Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslocalizedstring

I want to use NSLocalizedString to change languages for Mac not for IOS. Here are the steps I have done. However, when I relaunch the app, the language still does not change.

1. Add new xib files as well as NSLocalizedString

[image]

2. Create a NSMenuItems.

[image]

3. Then I created one IBAction and connected with all the NSMenuItems with that function.

   ```
   -(IBAction)languageDidSelect: (id)sender
   {   
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[languages objectAtIndex: [sender tag]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     [sender setState: NSOnState];

     [self relaunch];
    }

    -(void)relaunch
    {
       isRelaunch = true; //boolean variable
       [[NSApplication sharedApplication]terminate:nil];
       exit(0);
    }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification 
    {
       //relaunch the app via NSTask
       if (isRelaunch) {
          NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
          NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
          [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/open"];
          [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:appPath, nil]];
          [task launch];

          //After finished relaunch, run the following function
          [self finishedRelaunch];
         }
    }

    -(void)finishedRelaunch
    {
        NSArray* langs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"AppleLanguages"];

        //setLanguage function is using to change the NSMenuItem state
       if ([langs count] > 0) [self setLanguage: [langs objectAtIndex: 0]];
       else [self setLanguage: nil];
    }

     //Use to set NSMenuItem state
     - (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)name
    {
       NSString* ident = [NSLocale canonicalLocaleIdentifierFromString: name];

       [[[languageMenu submenu] itemWithTag: 0] setState: (nil == name) ? NSOnState : NSOffState];
       [[[languageMenu submenu] itemWithTag: 1] setState: ([ident isEqual: @"en"]) ? NSOnState : NSOffState];
       [[[languageMenu submenu] itemWithTag: 2] setState: ([ident isEqual: @"de"]) ? NSOnState : NSOffState];
           ...
    }
   ```

   4. The result is, when I checked the plist, “AppleLanguages” section did changed to new language (from jp -> de). However, the xib files and string did not change at all. Could you guys tell me how to fix it?

   [image]

Thanks!!! (My development target is 10.5, and my base SDK is OS X 10.7)

Comment: If you log out and log in again after your change what happens? What does defaults read tell you ?

Comment: Actually, the name in -(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)name gives me back the initial of what I selected in the NSmenuItems like "de". But it will throw me error says  "-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100021c58" and the check mark on the NSMenuItems will not be changed also.

Comment: Do the localized nibs load if you use the standard way of changing preferred language priority in System Preferences then relaunching your app?

Comment: No.Why? I already added those nibs for different languages. :(

Comment: Well, it helps to know if your nibs actually load correctly with the standard user settings.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that and I tried to change preferred language in system but mine app still not load correctly. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `AppleLanguages` key is supposed to be an `NSArray`, not a string.    Try creating an array with just your prescribed language in it and setting that in preferences instead of the string.

So, instead of

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    setObject:[languages objectAtIndex: [sender tag]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject: 
        [languages objectAtIndex: [sender tag]]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

I also noticed you have an `AppleLanguages` key in your Bundle file.  Why is that?   You shouldn'tneed it there.

Once your app has run, double check the value of your `NSUserDefaults` by using `defaults read <app_bundle_id>` and check the `AppleLanguages` key and see that it is set and is an array.   If that's set correctly, it should affect the next launch of your app

Comment: It helps me to fix the error "-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100021c58", but I did not see any changes. Is it because I used wrong way to relaunch the application?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two steps to figure out this problem:

1. Like gaige said : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
   setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject: 
       [languages objectAtIndex: [sender tag]]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
2. Then change the initial to full name, in my case is change the "jp" to "Japanese"

Then it will work.